# Geary - spell cheks with other language

Tags: 20.04, language-support, spell-checking, geary

This is my first question to the community so be kind with me if not properly presented :-)

New to Linux (20.04 installed), I am testing various e-mail clients. I really like **Geary**, but there is an annoying issue with spell checks, that propose only English variations and I need french on top.

In the Activities/setting menus, french is present, so is in Libreoffice writer and in Thundermail.

I researched on the web but did not find any precise response

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu Thierry,

Geary can use a couple of different dictionary sources and `hunspell` is generally the best one for people who use non-English languages. If you haven’t done so already, you can install `hunspell` like this:

```
sudo apt install hunspell hunspell-fr
```

This will install the dictionary as well as the main French dictionary. From there you can restart Geary. French should then appear n the available languages list.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Many thanks Matigo. Could not install hunspell-fr as it was already present. problem is still the same problem. 18 versions of english but not french in Geary

Comment: Which version of Geary are you running? Is it a snap or flatpak version? 

Comment: flatpak, geary 3.38.1

Comment: Have you run a `flatpak update` recently?

Comment: yes - no update needed

Answer (score 1):

I've been there too, and changing the locale after installing new flatpak app to get the language does solve the problem, but there's better solution, involving a bit of terminal.

Just two commands:

```
flatpak config --set extra-languages "fr_FR"
flatpak update
```

This will make your further flatpak installation obey and install French for any new app.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :). I des-installed Geary, changed back the main Activities/settings default to French, rebooted then re-installed Geary. French has been added to English in the spell check options of Geary, then change the main Activities/Settings back to English

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get spell check initially, after installing aspell and aspell-en, and reboot, it worked. So I assume if you install aspell-xx and reboot, it should work. I never got hunsepll to work.